# Angular: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' . The response had HTTP status code 500

Tags: javascript, angular

While am trying to upload a file by calling api it shows the error 500 server error and No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:5000' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 500.
And this is my code....

component.html

```
<input type="file" id="file" name=" file" (change)="onFileSelected($event)">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="onUpload()">Submit </button>
```

component.ts

```
selectedFile: File = null;   

 constructor(private router:Router,private http:HttpClient) { } 

 onFileSelected(event){
       this.selectedFile =<File>event.target.files[0];     
       console.log(event);    
 } 

onUpload(){     
   const fd = new FormData(); 
   fd.append('image', this.selectedFile, this.selectedFile.name); 
   this.http.post('api',fd).subscribe(
      response=> { 
             console.log(response);  
      }); 
}
```

Comment: Have a read [about CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing).

Answer (score 1):

You need to setup a reverse proxy configuration for your angular application. For development you can follow this guide:
https://juristr.com/blog/2016/11/configure-proxy-api-angular-cli/

Answer (score 0):

pls try following...

```
selectedFile: File = null;   

 constructor(private router:Router,private http:HttpClient) { } 

 onFileSelected(event){
       this.selectedFile =<File>event.target.files[0];     
       console.log(event);    
 } 

onUpload(){     
   const fd = new FormData(); 
   fd.append('image', this.selectedFile, this.selectedFile.name);

    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    this.http.post('api',fd, options).subscribe(
      response=> { 
             console.log(response);  
      }); 
}
```

also , follow below link to see how to set up dev server proxy if api and angular is deployed in different domain.:

[Angular 5 + Spring MVC : getting null http session on server for next request after login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48373939/angular-5-spring-mvc-getting-null-http-session-on-server-for-next-request-af)

Answer (score -1):

If you need it just for test purposes, install CORS plugin for Google Chrome

> https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en

Comment: That's a bad advice, it's "just for test" advice :)

Comment: I thought its needed just for test purposes. I misread it. sry.